# Temporal Data set

Tags: multiple-regression, model, trend

I have a fishery data set of fourteen years in a tropical region. This kind of information is quite rare in ecological studies.The data were monthly collected and the set has 2 annual gaps and a gap of 3 months along years. I'm not interested in seasonality, but in trend and relationships with others independent variables. Is this a problem for me? Should I use only part of data, when it not has gaps between months? By the fact that I will contextualize it with the explicative variables and/or factors, Can I use all data set for analysis?